# How to open a file in the PC's default text editing software (not the default associated app)?

Tags: c#, .net

Working in C#, I would like to start a process and open a file in the default *text editing program,* which is not necessarily the default program association for that filetype.

For example, say I wanted to open an html file.  The default association for that file may be firefox.  How could I open it in the default text editor (e.g. Notepad, Notepad++, etc.)?

Thanks for your help.

**edit:** The comment below said there is no way to set a default text editing program.  Very well, is there a way to *pretend* that the file is a txt file?

Comment: That concept doesn't exist. Default programs are only associated by file type or protocol. Have you ever seen a way to set your default text editing program without doing it by file type or protocol?

Comment: You use the lpClass to treat the file as a text file. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445960/using-shellexecuteex-to-open-an-executable-also-specifying-an-lpclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its in the registry:

```
    string edit = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell\edit\command", null, null);

    edit = edit.Replace("%1", @"c:\temp.txt");

    Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c " + edit);
```

This will invoke the command it uses when you rightclick->Edit a text file instead of rightclick->Open